# Find the digit occurring the most in a range of prime numbers

Tags: math, fastest-algorithm

Find the digit which occurs the most in a range of prime numbers.

#### Input:

Two numbers, `p` and `q`, specifying the range; the range includes both `p` and `q`.

#### Output:

The digit that occurs most frequently in that range of prime numbers. If two or more digits are tied, all of them should be outputted.

#### Winning Criteria:

Fastest code to complete *(insert 1+ specific test cases here)* wins.

### Example

**Input:**  `21 40`

**Output:**  `3`

### Explanation

The prime numbers in the range `21 40` are `23`, `29`, `31`, and `37`. Within these numbers, `2` occurs 2 times, `3` occurs 3 times, and `1`, `7` and `9` occur 1 time each. Thus, as `3` appears the most, the correct output is `3`.

Comment: I've added the tag corresponding to your chosen winning criterion. Please have a look at the [tag wiki](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/fastest-algorithm/info) and consider clarifying especially the second and third question there.

Comment: "*Two numbers p and q specifying the range*" how? Inclusive, exclusive, one of each? What should the output be if there's a tie? What should it be if the tie is because there are no primes in the range? And are you *really* sure you want to do a [tag:fastest-algorithm] which involves primality testing, bearing in mind that the running time of the best known algorithm depends on the correctness or otherwise of a long-open problem (the generalised Riemann hypothesis)?

Comment: I think this could be an OK question if the winning criterion is least number of bytes, and all of Peter's questions are answered.

Comment: @PeterTaylor First of all Primality testing has a poly time algorithm (Agarwal,2002) . Second by fast algorithm I never said it has to be poly time, I just wanted an algorithm better than just bruteforce. Third I have specified range as inclusive.

Comment: I know that *PRIMES is in P*: the developments of AKS techniques are precisely what's behind my comment about the GRH. The best AKS variant is in Õ(n^6) if the GRH is false, and Õ(n^4) if the GRH is true. Moreover, the previous [tag:fastest-algorithm] question about primes has a few answers, *not a single one of which* has a stated score. I don't think [tag:fastest-algorithm] and primes are a good fit for each other.

Comment: @alienCoder Could you define more precisely what should happen in the case of finding two (or more) digits which occur the most, like if there are `4` threes _and_ fives? Also, what do you mean by _input_ and _output_? Function parameters and return value? STDIN and STDOUT?

Comment: 39 is divisible by 3. It's not prime.

Comment: @alienCoder What do you mean as least time complexity? Big O notation ? Note that two algorithms with the same time complexity given in terms of big O notation may differ in the time of execution by an arbitrarily big constant factor. Maybe consider [tag:fastest-code] instead? This could make this question more "popular".

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3

```
import collections
p=lambda n:n>1 and all(n%i for i in range(int(n**0.5),1,-1))
print(collections.Counter(''.join(map(str,filter(p,range(*map(int,raw_input().split(' '))))))).most_common(1)[0][0])
```

Probably not the best way it can be done, but a start. (**196 bytes**)

### Time Specs

Using Python's builtin code timer module, `timeit`, I got these times for each listed range.

```
(1,       11):      0.000084381103520
(1,      101):      0.000338881015778
(1,     1001):      0.003911740779880
(1,    10001):      0.071979818344100
(1,   100001):      1.785329985620000
(1,  1000001):     54.977741956700000
(1, 10000001):   1700.231099130000000
```

It can go over a range of a million numbers in under a minute.

### Usage

```
$ python test.py
21 41
3
$ python test.py
51 89
7
$ python test.py
201 501
3
```

### Ungolfed

```
import collections

def is_it_prime(n):
    if n > 1:
        if all(n % i for i in range(int(n ** 0.5), 1, -1)):
            return True
    return False

start, stop = raw_input.split(' ', 1)

primes = ""
for p in range(int(start), int(stop)):
    if is_it_prime(p):
        primes += str(p)

counter = collections.Counter(primes).most_common(1)
print(counter[0][0])
```

Comment: Just so you know, winning criteria is time complexity, not byte count :)

Comment: I saw; that's why I added the "Time Specs" section. :P @Shebang

Comment: Just making sure you know if you want to update you could un-golf to make updating much easier. Nice work though! :)

Comment: Added an ungolfed version. @Shebang

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica

```
 Print[""<>IntegerString[MaximalBy[Tally[Join@@IntegerDigits[Prime[Range[PrimePi[#1]+1,PrimePi[#2]]]]],Last][[;;,1]]&@@FromDigits/@StringSplit@InputString[]]]
```

### Time Specs

Using Mathematica's builtin timer, `AbsoluteTiming`, I got these times for each listed range.

```
f=MaximalBy[Tally[Join@@IntegerDigits[Prime[Range[PrimePi[#1]+1,PrimePi[#2]]]]],Last][[;;,1]]&
Grid[Table[{1,10^x+1,AbsoluteTiming[f[1,10^x+1]][[1]]},{x,1,7}]]
```

Returns:

```
1        11   0.0003388
1       101   0.0003645
1      1001   0.0016222
1     10001   0.0040902
1    100001   0.0267737
1   1000001   0.211297
1  10000001   4.55387
1 100000001  43.9889
```

It can go over a range of a hundred million numbers in under a minute.

### Usage

```
wolframscript -f primedigitcount.wls
? 21 41
3
wolframscript -f primedigitcount.wls
? 51 89
7
wolframscript -f primedigitcount.wls
? 201 501
3
```

### Ungolfed

Takes the space-seperated input and converts it to two integers

```
a = FromDigits/@StringSplit@InputString[]
```

PrimePi is the inverse function of Prime, so this gets all the primes between the two a's. The `+1` is that if the operand is not prime, it gets the first prime below it, but we want a prime above the smaller number.

```
b = Prime[Range[PrimePi[#1]+1,PrimePi[#2]]&@@a
```

Turns every number in the list into a list of it's digits, and then concatenates all the lists into one list of all the digits

```
c = Join@@IntegerDigits[b]
```

Mathematica has a nice built-in for turning a list into unique items and their counts.

```
d = Tally[c]
```

Takes a list of the item (or items) who has the largest count, and strips off the tally.

```
e = MaximalBy[d,Last][[;;,1]]
```

Converts every number in the list to a string, concatenates them, and prints it.

```
Print[""<>IntegerString[e]]
```

### Conjecture:

In hope that somebody more mathematically inclined could find this to be an O(n) problem, I leave you this conjecture:

If the first number is kept as 1, and the 2nd number tends to be large (n>100), the result will be no more than two of 1, 3, or 7.

Comment: I don't know Mathematica so I can't prove it, but the timings definitely do point towards this being \$O(n)\$ (as you multiply the upper limit by 10, the timings also increase by a factor of 10).

Comment: Yep, re-read and remembered that my variable is 10^x, not just x, I should state it as O(log(n)). If the pattern is logarithmically cyclical, then it could be ~O(1).